# Compute $E[v^TQv]$ if $v$ is normal $(0,Q^{-1}) $ and $Q$ is Wishart $(w,\Psi)$

Tags: probability, matrices, expectation

suppose 
$$
x_t\sim Normal(x\mid\mu,\Sigma)
$$
where $x_t\in R^{N}$and
$$
x_t=Ax_{t-1}+v_t (Eq.1)
$$
where 
$$
v_t\sim Normal(v_t\mid 0,Q^{-1})
$$
and $Q$ is a $N\times N$ random matrix
$$
Q\sim Wishart (w,\Psi)
$$
where $w$ is a real number and $\Psi\in R^{N\times N}$ is a semi-positive matrix of real values.

we want to compute
$$
E[(x_t-Ax_{t-1})^TQ(x_t-Ax_{t-1})]
$$

what I have done is (Using Eq.1):
$$
E[(x_t-Ax_{t-1})^TQ(x_t-Ax_{t-1})]=E[(Ax_{t-1}+v_t-Ax_{t-1})^TQ(Ax_{t-1}+v_t-Ax_{t-1})]
$$
$$
=E[v_t^TQv_t]=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{n^\prime=1}^N E[v_{t_n}^TQ_{nn^\prime}v_{t_{n^\prime}}]
$$
$$
=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{n^\prime=1}^N E[E[v_{t_n}Q_{nn^\prime}v_{t_{n^\prime}}\mid Q_{nn^\prime}]]=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{n^\prime=1}^N E[Q_{nn^\prime}E[v_{t_n}v_{t_{n^\prime}}\mid Q_{nn^\prime}]]
$$
$$
=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{n^\prime=1}^N E[Q_{nn^\prime}Q^*_{nn^\prime}]
$$
where $Q^*$ is the inverse matrix of $Q$.

How can I proceed with the equation?

Comment: Starting at $E(v^TQv)$, please separate what is random from what is not, for example, $E(v_kQ_{k\ell}v_\ell)$ is simply $Q_{k\ell}E(v_kv_\ell)$ since $Q_{k\ell}$ is a *number*. Can you simplify the expansion of $E(v^TQv)$ now?

Comment: I added more information to the question. both $v_t$ and $Q$ are random. $v_t$ is a random vector and $Q$ is a random matrix. So I can not simplify it more

Comment: *Yes you can*... Now, use that $Q$ is symmetric hence, for every $k$, $$\sum_\ell Q_{k,\ell}Q^*_{k,\ell}=\sum_\ell Q^*_{k,\ell}Q_{\ell,k}=(Q^*Q)_{k,k}=\ldots$$

Comment: is it correct that the result is equal to $1$? because $Q*=Q^{-1}$, then $$E[(Q*Q)_{k,k}]=E[(Q^{-1}*Q)_{k,k}]=E[I_{k,k}]=1$$

Comment: Yes, each $(Q^*Q)_{k,k}$ is $1$.